# How to add a onclick event on an element with custom input for the function

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a HTML element and i have a lot of them but i am only showing one because it is easier the only difference between them is the number in the id `<div class="block" id="block0"></div>`

and i want to give it a onclick with a javascript so i get this
`<div class="block" id="block0" onclick="blockClicked(0)"></div>`

and what i mean by custom input i what the input for the function to be the id of the div or just the number in the id. what i mean is that if i have another element with the id of block1 the onclick should be onclick="blockClicked(1)". but all pages i've found so far only shows how to give it a function with a input that is the same everytime. This might have already been answered if it has i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select all your block elements with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop over them with a [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method. For each block listen for the `click` event with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). When the click event happens you'll want to figure out which element was clicked and get the `id` property of that element.

This way you can add more data in the form of [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to your block element and read the data from the `onBlockClick` function with the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) property on the block element.

```
// Select all block elements.
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

// Is called when a block is clicked.
const onBlockClick = event => {
  const { currentTarget } = event; // currentTarget is element we are listening to, so the block element.
  const { id } = currentTarget; // Get the id from the block element.
  console.log(id); // Now you have an id variable which you can do something with.
});

// Loop over each block and listen for the click event.
blocks.forEach(block => {
  block.addEventListener('click', onBlockClick);
});
```

Comment: If you don't use an arrow function as event handler, you can simply use `this` to access the element the handler is bound to. Or use `event.currentTarget`. No need for `closest` really.

Comment: @FelixKling you learn something everyday. Always thought to use the `target` on the event as I thought that `currentTarget` had shabby support. Not comfortable using `this` outside of an OOP context, though. But I've incorporated your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
const block = document.getElementById('block0')
block.addEventListener('click',(mouseEvent) => { /* whatever you want to do on click */  
blockClicked(0) })
```

If you want you can loop through all your elements and add them an event listener if they do have the same behavior

```js
const elements = [...document.getElementsByClass('block')]
elements.foreach((el,i) => { 
                           el.addEventListener('click', 
                               mouseEvent => { 
                                    /* your event managment */ 
                                    blockClicked(i)  
                              }) 
                       })
```

Check this link to learn more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: all this does is it would make <div class="block" id="block0" onclick="blockClicked()"></div> and not <div class="block" id="block0" onclick="blockClicked(0)"></div> as what i was asking for

Comment: In your code you can do whatever you want, so if you want to pass something like a parameter you can, if your blockClicked function is already existing you can just call it in the eventListener with the parameter you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to access the element the handler is bound to and therefore you can use `this.id` to access it's ID.

While binding event handlers with `addEventListener` is better overall, the minimal changes to your current code would be something like:

```
<div
  class="block"
  id="block0"
  onclick="blockClicked(Number(this.id.replace('block')))">
</div>
```

---

No matter the way you choose, something to consider is to not use `id` just for piggybacking data, but use a [`data-*` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead:

```
<div
  class="block"
  data-id="0"
  onclick="blockClicked(Number(this.dataset.id))">
</div>
```